# Caffe build : ln: target '.build_release/tools/finetune_net' is not a directory

Tags: compiling, make, caffe

i'm trying to compile caffe that i got from https://github.com/SeokjuLee/VPGNet.git. i'm using CPU Only, i've installed the required dependencies, but when i try to make all, i got this error

```
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/finetune_net.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/convert_driving_data.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/extract_features.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/net_speed_benchmark.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/train_net.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/device_query.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/test_net.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/convert_imageset.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin
ln: target '.build_release/tools/finetune_net' is not a directory
make: *** [Makefile:565: .build_release/tools/finetune_net] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

i have tried to googled the error but i just can't find the answer
my system config

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Opencv4.4.0
- Python 3.8
- gcc 9.3.0

here's what my [Makefile](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OcChy4buV_xB6udVEmfTqRmOi4f-x7WH4RYdKBxUOOI/edit?usp=sharing) and [Makefile.config](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17r8RosyummstMxpX77fiFBciwqW_rlext8RL9mQgOoE/edit?usp=sharing) look. i have tried to remove finetune_net.cpp out of the directory but it just changes the target from finetune_net to net_speed_bechmark and so on. i also tried to comment line 563-565 but the error become much worse. please tell me your idea